# Creating a model with a ManyToMany relationship to users, how to extend Users information

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a model that has (perhaps several) ManyToMany relationships with users. Basically the model is suppose to hold an event (Madklub) in which users can join. Now this I already successfully implemented, however now I want to make the users be able to bring guests (Users not registered), now this simply need to be a number on how many guests a specific user is bringing, but the amount of guests needs to be tied to the user somehow, so that in case the user leaves the event then the guests are also decremented from the total amount of guests.

The following is my current model,

```
DIET_OPTIONS = (
        ('vegan', 'Vegan'),
        ('vegetarian', 'Vegetarian'),
        ('meat', 'Meat')
    )

class Madklub(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name="owner", null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dish = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    guests = ???
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    vegan_participants = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="vegan_participants", blank=True)
    vegetarian_participants = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="vegetarian_participants", blank=True)
    meat_participants = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="meat_participants", blank=True)
    diet = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(choices=DIET_OPTIONS, max_length=10, default="vegetarian")
    )
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date',)

class GuestInfo(models.Model):
    ???
```

So right now I have it so that when a user joins the Madklub (event) they choose one of three options (meat, vegetarian, vegan). And depending on they choice they are put into a particular relationship in the model. However now I need to handle their guests, their guests do not have to select an option, they should automatically have the option selected by the User bringing the guests.

So my current idea is to create a separate model which should hold some information. Either it should hold all the participant information (both Users and guests), and then a Madklub has a OneToOne field with the participant information. Or the Madklub should hold a ManyToMany field with the GuestInfo(Meat/Vegetarian/Vegan) and then that model also holds an integer value with the amount of guests.

I hope it makes sense, I am not sure what the best way to do this is and I am also not sure how the implementation would work, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the current Madklub is a bit too heavy-weight. Just an idea:

```
class Madklub(models.Model):
    # event-specific fields like owner, dish date, active

class Registration(models.Model):
    # One Registration corresponds to one single Madklub
    madklub = models.ForeignKey(Madklub, ...)
    # One Registration corresponds to one single participant (MyUser)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, ...)
    # Choices are given by Madklub
    food_preference = models.CharField(choices=DIET_OPTIONS, max_length=10, default="vegetarian")
    # How many invitations this participant has
    number_invitation = models.IntegerField(...) # if you want a fast aggregation of diet options

class Invitation(models.Model): # turned out not necessary as the discussion went on
    registration = models.ForeignKey(Registration, ...)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, ...)
```

So the diet option is stored in the registration model, which is tied to a specific participant (non-guest). Depending on how fast you want your aggregation to work, you can add a sum field in the Registration model for the number of guests, or you can just prefetch_related from the Madklub all the way down to the Invitations.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. How would I track who has which guests (non-user guests added by a user)? Also should the Madklub model then not have any relationships? How would I then query the madklub to retrieve all the partipants and their chosen food_preference?

Comment: Ah missed the part that a guest is not necessarily a `MyUser`. Then the `guest` field in the `Invitation` model would have to be a foreign key to yet another model (`Guest` or `ContactInfo`?).

For "How would I track who has which guests": That is the reverse foreign key relationship from `Registration` to `Invitation`.

Comment: Basically all I need the non-user guest to be is a number, I'm not really concerned with any of their information. So the extra model would simply be a number I guess? Also what do you mean by reverse foreign key? And for retrieving all the Madklubs with all it's participants, diet, date, active dish and so forth, how would I do that?

Comment: For "How would I then query the madklub to retrieve all the partipants and their chosen food_preference": If we are not counting the food preference of the guests, then it should be straight-forward (Madklub prefetch_related to registrations. If we are also counting the guests' preference, probably we would need several annotates, something like `Madklub.objects.prefetch_related('registrations__invitations').annotate(vegan_count=Sum('registration__number_invitation')).annotate(meat_count=Sum(...))`, given that `registrations` and `invitations` are the `related_name` of the corresponding FK

Comment: "all I need the non-user guest to be is a number" - then we won't need an `Invitation` model, just the field `number_invitation` should already be ok. To retrieve ALL Madklubs with all their participants, I think you just need `Madklub.objects.all().prefetch_related('registrations')`, with this you wouldn't have to fire a query for every single Madklub

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll have a go at it, might get stuck at some point and perhaps ask about something again

Comment: In the `Sum(...)` above, you probably need a `Q` object there: `sum('number_invitation', filter=Q(food_preference='vegan'))`

Comment: May I ask, the way you have structured the model now. It should be so that, each Madklub has an owner (User) and it can have multiple participants (Users), each participant can have multiple guests (represented as an integer), is this the case? I am having troubles understanding the model 100%. To clear it up, the Registration model is related to a Madklub through the FK. Then it has the participant, is this a single User or multiple users, my guess is a single user? However shouldn't the Madklub model then have a ManyToMany relationship to the Registration model?

Comment: Hey, "is this the case?" - yes, that is exactly the case (or how I would model this app).  "the Registration model is related to a Madklub through the FK" - each `Registration` is correpsonding to one user as participant, for one single `Madklub` event. I would imagine this `Registration` as an entrance ticket to that event, with an additional ability to take guests :). From `Registration` to `Madklub`, it should be a FK relationship, since one `Registration` only belongs to one single `Madklub`

Comment: An alternative implementation would be not having this `Registration` model explicitly, but to have a many-to-many relationship from the `Madclub` to `MyUser` directly. In detail, the `through` field would be more or less our `Registration` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through. But that would probably make the food preference part hard to model

Comment: Okay, so that is why to query the `Madklub` I have to use `prefetch_related`, since the `Madklub` model actually doesn't have any relations itself. They way the diet/food_preference works is that a `Madklub` has a list of possible diet options, then when the User registers they select one of those diet options, and this is the `food_preference` in the Registration Model, correct? I have added a diet field to the Madklub which is an ArrayField of the chosen diet options for the `Madklub`.

Comment: Correct, that is the `food_preference`. I have never worked with `ArrayField` yet, but a short search suggests it only works with `PostgreSQL`. If you are 100% sure your DB stays `PostgreSQL`, then it's totally fine. Otherwise you would just need a nother `Diet` model pointing to `Madklub` either via FK or `ManyToMany`, depending on how you want to model `Diet`

Comment: Yep, I am quite sure that I will stick with PostgreSQL and I already made a model using `ArrayField`. Thank you so much for your input and help. If you don't mind me asking more questions (I am rather new to Django), do you have any hints or something to create the serializer, this is what I've got (sorry for formatting),

Comment: class MadklubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    owner = UserSerializer(read_only = True)


    class Meta:
        model = Madklub
        fields = ('owner', 'date', 'diet', 'active', 'dish')


class RegistrationSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    madklub = MadklubSerializer(read_only = True)
    participant = UserSerializer(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ('madklub', 'participant', 'food_preference', 'number_guests')

Comment: Hi, very unfortunately I have never worked with rest framework, so I am afraid I cannot help you further on the serializer part :)

Comment: Ahh, bummer. Anyways thank you! Hopefully I figure it out

Comment: Sure, best luck!

Comment: Hey, running the following `Madklub.objects.filter(date__gte=date.today()).prefetch_related('registrations')`, gives me the following error `Cannot find 'registrations' on Madklub object, 'registrations' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`. Any idea?

Comment: Probably either you have not defined the `related_name` for the FK `madklub` as `registrations` in `Registration` model, or you have not migrated yet :)

Comment: No, the FK to `madklub` in the `Registration` model has `related_name='madklub'`

Comment: Right that kind of fixed it. Now I think I have a problem with my serializer, so I'll try to figure that out. Thank you again!